# S3 PreSignedUrl Upload | SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Code for generating presignedUrl.

```
public static String createPresignedUrl(final String region, final String bucketName, final String keyName,
            final Map<String, String> metadata) {
        try (final S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder().region(Region.of(region)).build()) {

            final PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .metadata(metadata)
                .build();

            final PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) // The URL expires in 10 minutes.
                .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
                .build();

            final PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);
            final String myURL = presignedRequest.url().toString();
            log.info("Presigned URL to upload a file to: [{}]", myURL);
            log.info("HTTP method: [{}]", presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());

            return presignedRequest.url().toExternalForm();
        }
    }
```

Invoked preSignedUrl

```
https://craft-documents.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/b744ad14-eea5-4554-98ec-1f0683cdf470/b40a9029-12f9-4303-be8c-19fad22f2e12?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240124T065744Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-meta-content-type&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAWIRY6IEWUJBQOMPB%2F20240124%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Signature=e7d2bb60f4e19c7e13eff592809a268b84b4990e77b5a79a577b72e573be985b
```

In metadata passing

```
"Content-Type": "application/pdf"
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAWIRY6IEWUJBQOMPB</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20240124T065744Z
20240124/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request
ccf735c83e7f10456e40e7fc110203d2f2d4392f5e8faff708d6ccb841472a4f</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>e7d2bb60f4e19c7e13eff592809a268b84b4990e77b5a79a577b72e573be985b</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 34 30 31 32 34 54 30 36 35 37 34 34 5a 0a 32 30 32 34 30 31 32 34 2f 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 63 63 66 37 33 35 63 38 33 65 37 66 31 30 34 35 36 65 34 30 65 37 66 63 31 31 30 32 30 33 64 32 66 32 64 34 33 39 32 66 35 65 38 66 61 66 66 37 30 38 64 36 63 63 62 38 34 31 34 37 32 61 34 66</StringToSignBytes>
    <CanonicalRequest>PUT
/b744ad14-eea5-4554-98ec-1f0683cdf470/b40a9029-12f9-4303-be8c-19fad22f2e12
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAWIRY6IEWUJBQOMPB%2F20240124%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20240124T065744Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-meta-content-type
host:craft-documents.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-meta-content-type:

host;x-amz-meta-content-type
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
    <CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 62 37 34 34 61 64 31 34 2d 65 65 61 35 2d 34 35 35 34 2d 39 38 65 63 2d 31 66 30 36 38 33 63 64 66 34 37 30 2f 62 34 30 61 39 30 32 39 2d 31 32 66 39 2d 34 33 30 33 2d 62 65 38 63 2d 31 39 66 61 64 32 32 66 32 65 31 32 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 57 49 52 59 36 49 45 57 55 4a 42 51 4f 4d 50 42 25 32 46 32 30 32 34 30 31 32 34 25 32 46 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 34 30 31 32 34 54 30 36 35 37 34 34 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 36 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 25 33 42 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 6d 65 74 61 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 63 72 61 66 74 2d 64 6f 63 75 6d 65 6e 74 73 2e 73 33 2e 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 6d 65 74 61 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3a 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 6d 65 74 61 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes>
    <RequestId>3V1NBDFA7SHCBY77</RequestId>
    <HostId>+yZMA01KYT7jShHftDYUKbwN5xktAXE94fYmb0cW+Hm6rnXqs9ZOKzdmW6rYtaP4GtjNm008lk8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

i'm trying to upload a pdf to s3 using preSignedUrl. But getting error SignatureDoesNotMatch.

1. Do i need to pass hash of file in metadata ?
2. How to fix this ?

Comment: How are you generating the pre-signed URL?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
added code for generating preSignedUrl

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it after adding a header with prefix

```
x-amz-meta-
```

Overall added these headers

```
Content-Dispostion:attachment; filename="abc.pdf"
Content-Type:application/pdf
x-amz-meta-Content-Type:application/pdf
```